# Xming won't start if running as super user

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, wireshark, xming

Scenario:

I am attempting to run [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) through [xming server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xming) located on a windows 8.1 machine off of a [Raspberry Pi B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b-plus/) that is hardwired to a [Wifi Pineapple Mark 5](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/wifi-pineapple?variant=81044992).

Xming successfully launches with the following command

```
pi@raspberrypi~$ wireshark -i interface name
```

However when I attempt to access (any of the interfaces including one generated with airmon-ng) I get

> "You don't have permission to access this interface"

from wireshark.

So naturally I say, "Derp, you need to run it with sudo"

When I run

```
pi@raspberrypi~$ sudo wireshark -i interface name
```

xming doesn't connect and it says

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
(wireshark:3123): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

I am at a total loss as to why this is happening.

I researched it a little and most suggest adding

> "ForwardX11Trusted yes"

to my sshd_config file but when I do this and attempt to restart my ssh server it says that it is a bad key. I also tried ssh_config. I didn't get a restart error but I still experienced the same xming issues.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal. You've connected to your Pi as user `pi`, asking `ssh` (or PuTTY in this case) to forward your X connection to your desktop. This only allows user `pi` on the Pi to access your X server on your desktop; when you run `wireshark` as `root`, since `root` on your Pi doesn't have access to your X server you see the error message you've given.

I'll give you the `ssh` solution, but it's **the wrong approach** in this case; I'll give you the right approach for `wireshark` as well.

In general, to run an X program as some other user than the user with which you've connected to a remote machine, you need to merge the X authority information. In this case, to allow `root` to connect to your desktop, run the following on your Pi:

```
xauth extract - $DISPLAY | sudo xauth merge -
```

This extracts your `pi` user's X authority and merges it with your `root` user's X authority. You may get a warning about `/root/.Xauthority` not existing; that doesn't matter, `xauth` will create the file for you. You should now be able to run `wireshark` as `root`.

**But** running `wireshark` as `root` isn't recommended; security holes are found regularly in Wireshark... `/usr/share/doc/wireshark/README.Debian` gives two possible approaches. The first is to run `dumpcap` as `root` to capture all the traffic you're interested in, then run `wireshark` to analyse the generated output (and you could run `dumpcap` on your Pi, then use Wireshark on your desktop computer). The second is to add your `pi` user to the `wireshark` group and reconfigure Wireshark to allow members of the `wireshark` group to capture traffic; you can do this by running the following on your Pi:

```
adduser pi wireshark
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

and pick "Yes" in the configuration screen. Then run `wireshark` as `pi`.

Comment: So I attempted both of your solutions and they both seem to be on the correct path and exactly what I am looking for. That said, the first method results with "xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to read any entries from file "(stdin)"" and your second one results in "adduser: The group `wireshark' does not exist.
" Any ideas?

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because though it wasn't what did it, it led me to the correct answer. I did need to configure privgs. Found the answer here https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges